# Function to approximate long numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question I have a value that I need to divide and make the values ​​without infinite decimals when divided by an odd number
example:

5 values ​​that add up to 200 divided by three people

this result is: 66.66666666666667

I want to avoid this, so that an approximation is made like:

2 people would stay with 65
and one person with 70

my code:

```
const test = [
  {  price: 5, quantity: 10 },
  {  price: 10, quantity: 10 },
  { price: 5, quantity: 10 },
];

const persons = ['person 1', 'person 2', 'person 3']

const total = testList
  .map((test ) => test .unitPrice * test .quantity)
  .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current);

    const division =  total/persons.length
```

I need a way that in the end the total is 200 divided for 3 people, without having decimal numbers

Comment: if you do `Math.floor(200/3)` and then sum what you get up you get a value less than 200, then if you do `200-<what you got>` you get how much is left to redistribute

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to make sure that the distribution takes into account the lowest price? That's why you want to end up with `65, 65, 70` and not `66, 67, 67`?

Comment: @blex sorry the correct is 66,67,67 my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to figure out how many will remain. Remove them, divide it, than loop to add the remaining to the other buckets until you run out.

```js
const total = 200
const numParts = 3
let extras = total % numParts;
const base = (total - extras) / numParts
const portions = new Array(numParts).fill(base)
for (let i = 0; i < numParts && extras > 0; i++) {
  portions[i]++;
  extras--;
}
console.log(portions);
```